# I have 4 columns with Sum and Count Functions. I want to convert 4 columns in 4 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I used this query

```
Select Count(PostID) As TotalPost,sum(Impressions) As TotalImpression, sum(Likes) As TotalLikes, Sum(Shares) As Shares, Sum(Engagements)AS Engagements
From dm.vSocialMediaPost;
```

Result:

```
TotalPost TotalImpression TotalLikes   Shares  Engagements
712      |  1874273      |  29418     | 4231|   65326
```

I want result like

```
TotalPost             |712
TotalImpression       | 1874273      
TotalLikes            |29418  
Shares                |4231
Engagements           |65326
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What is the database?

Comment: I am using MS SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is a union query:

```
SELECT 'TotalPost' AS label, COUNT(*) AS total FROM dm.vSocialMediaPost
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TotalImpression', SUM(Impressions) FROM dm.vSocialMediaPost
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TotalLikes', SUM(Likes) FROM dm.vSocialMediaPost
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Shares', SUM(Shares) FROM dm.vSocialMediaPost
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Engagements', SUM(Engagements) FROM dm.vSocialMediaPost;
```

Comment: @KamilGosciminski It came from my cell phone.  I could have beaten Gordon on my MacBook.

Comment: You better not fight in here ;)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is multiple aggregations:

```
Select 'TotalPost', count(*)
From dm.vSocialMediaPost
union all
select 'TotalImpression', sum(Impressions)
From dm.vSocialMediaPost
union all
select 'TotalLikes', sum(Likes)
From dm.vSocialMediaPost
union all 
select 'Shares', Sum(Shares)
From dm.vSocialMediaPost
union all
select 'Engagements', Sum(Engagements)
From dm.vSocialMediaPost;
```

However, because SQL Server supports lateral joins, the best method uses `apply`:

```
select v.*
from (select Count(PostID) As TotalPost, sum(Impressions) As TotalImpression, sum(Likes) As TotalLikes, Sum(Shares) As Shares, Sum(Engagements) as Engagements
      from dm.vSocialMediaPost
     ) x cross apply
     (values ('TotalPost', TotalPost),
             ('TotalImpression', TotalImpression),
             ('TotalLikes', TotalLikes),
             ('Shares', Shares),
             ('Engagements', Engagements)
     ) v(which, val);
```

This is "best" because it requires aggregating (and hence reading) the table only once.  It should be significantly faster than multiple aggregations.

Answer (score 1):

You might use `unpivot` keyword as :

```
select title, value 
  from
     ( Select Count(PostID) As TotalPost,
              sum(Impressions) As TotalImpression, 
              sum(Likes) As TotalLikes, 
              Sum(Shares) As Shares, 
              Sum(Engagements)AS Engagements
         From vSocialMediaPost ) p
unpivot  
   (value for Title in
      (TotalPost, TotalImpression, TotalLikes, Shares, Engagements)  
) unpvt;
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/JZCFM57747)